# Create Tikz Picture With These Specifications

Tags: tikz-pgf

Ciao, I am trying to create a tikz figure as shown in the image. Here is my code

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
  \node[rectangle] (a1) {box 1};
     \node[rectangle,below right=of a1] (a2) {box 2};
    \node[rectangle,above right=of a1] (a3) {box 3};

    \foreach \i/\j/\txt/\p in {% start node/end node/text/position
      a1/a2/1-2/below,
      a1/a3/1-3/above,
      a2/a3/2-3/below} \draw [myarrow] (\i) -- node[sloped,font=\small,\p] {\txt} (\j);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am not sure how to add the rectangles; how to connect the arrows to the side edge; and how to make the arrows straight in situations when the box lengths are different--preferably the arrows will touch the center of the edge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Tikz` `shapes` library and describe the sides of nodes.

```
\documentclass[margin=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,shapes}
\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
 \tikzstyle{rect}=[ thick, draw=blue, rectangle, minimum width=100pt, 
  minimum height = 50pt, align=center]
  \node[rect] (a1) {box 1};
  \node[rect,below right=of a1] (a3) {box 3};
  \node[rect,above right=of a1] (a2) {box 2};
\draw[->] (a1.north)--(a2.west)node[midway,above,xshift=-2mm]{1-2};
\draw[->] (a1.south)--(a3.west)node[midway,below,xshift=-2mm]{1-3};
\draw[->] (a2.south)--(a3.north)node[midway,xshift=-3mm]{2-3};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a bunch. Two final questions; how can i slant 1-3 and 1-2 so they are angled with the arrows lines? Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwv1Y.png

Comment: @victoria, your welcome. Add sloped option to node, i.e, `node[midway,sloped,above,xshift=-2mm]{1-2};`Now you can remove the `xshift=-2mm`.